# CListCtrl::InsertItem succeeds but nothing displays

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CListCtrl in icon view, and I use InsertItem to add an item to the list control.  InsertItem returns success and using GetItemText etc to poll for data returns the text I sent in, the proper count of items, etc....  By all accounts, this should display, but it is not showing ANYTHING, YET the data is right.  I am at my WITS end with this.  I write this because I'm hoping somebody has a quick light bulb fix because I have been searching Google and keep coming up EMPTY!

This is some debug code I have to prove the values are "**correct**".  nRet is *never* -1, csText is never empty, nCount is right (ie if I call this code 3 times, nCount is 3), dwErr is 0 *always*....

```
LVITEM lvi = { 0 };
CString strItem = "TEST";
lvi.mask = LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.iItem = (int)(UINT)unIndexGrp;
lvi.iSubItem = (int)0;
lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)(strItem.GetBufferSetLength(strItem.GetLength() * 2));
lvi.iImage = (int)(UINT)unImageListIndex;

...

int nRet = vecLstCtrl[nGroupID]->InsertItem(&lvi);
DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
if (nGroupID > 0)
{
//ASSERT(FALSE);
    CImageList *pIL = vecLstCtrl[nGroupID]->GetImageList(LVSIL_NORMAL);
    int nCount = vecLstCtrl[nGroupID]->GetItemCount();
    CString csText = vecLstCtrl[nGroupID]->GetItemText(lvi.iItem, lvi.iSubItem);
    int nImgCount = pIL->GetImageCount();
    ASSERT(FALSE);
    return nRet;
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to help because you haven't provided enough code. I suggest you create a [MCVE].

Comment: Did you handle alright the CListCtrl header ? Look with attention here, and how to setup correctly the list control: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608/Using-the-List-Control

Comment: @flaviu2 OP says the list is in icon view so header columns would not affect it.

Comment: Give me a little while to create that example.

Comment: CListCtrl is a mature and reliable windows control, so when is not shown something, should be checked the setup of the control ... at least, I would do that. Yes, maybe is not header, because is icon view, but I would search the issue in this direction